# AppInsights - Monitor for Hung Processes

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We are looking at implementing AppInsights for our non-web application. One of the things that we want to monitor for is processes that may be "hung" for more than N number of seconds or minutes. I have been unable to find something built in that does this. The closest thing I have seen or thought of would be to log 2 custom events for the start and end of a process, and then have an alert for a custom log that queries events with no matching "end" event after N minutes.

Is there another way to monitor for hung processes using AppInsights that I am not seeing? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should let us know what's your project. And you just want to know if the process is hung via app insights? If it's that, I guess app insights would not send data when process is hung. I think you can add a little more events track in your code which may hung, and use app insights rest api to query those events periodically. I also created a [ticket](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues/287) in app insights home to track this issue.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Correct, it is a non website application that can have process and jobs that hang every so often if the users input bad data or jobs overlap and cause resource constraints etc. 

We are looking at app insights as a way of having a centralized place for the analytics of which jobs and processes are used most, and would like to also have a way to alert if process or job X does not finish in N minutes. I realize there are a number of ways to do this outside of Application Insights, but was hoping to find an easy way to do it through what they have set up.

Comment: You can read [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues/287) on github, and if it's not very clear to you, please continue comment on that thread. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you choose to use application insights, here is the suggestion just for your reference(but if you have another better solution, you can ignore this):

As per this [post](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues/287), you can leverage heartbeat feature, details as below:

```
    if this application runs more than several seconds, you can leverage heartbeat 
feature - it sends metric every N minutes/seconds (configurable) and the absence of such
 metric will indicate that application is no longer actively running. However, if 
Application Insights thread survives, then heartbeat will still be reported.    

    You can rely on presense/absense of the telemetry from this app in general as well as 
couple custom events as you outlined above - Azure Monitor allows to set an alert on 
analytics query, so you'll be able to craft a query that returns nothing in case of 
application issues and set an alert on 0 count returned by such a query.
```